# Exception Access Violation Error in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash

I keep receiving errors from Adobe Flash. I've tried reinstalling twice.

Here's my crash data - what does this mean?:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE AdobeCrashReport SYSTEM "AdobeCrashReporter.dtd">
<crashreport version="1.1" crVersion="2.5.0.01052007" applicationName="Adobe Flash CS4" applicationVersion="10.0.0" build="10.0.0.544">
    <time year="2012" month="2" day="2" hour="13" minute="43" second="48"/>
    <user guid="f7b8918a-9d95-47ab-b39b-efded583eee2"/>
    <system platform="windows" osversion="6.1.7601 SP 1.0" applicationlanguage="English (United States)" userlanguage="en_US" oslanguage="en_US" ram="4094" machine="AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor" model="AMD64 Family 16 Model 5 Stepping 3" cpuCount="4" cpuFreq="3100 MHz" busFreq=""/>
    <crash exception="EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" instruction="0x61fdd832">
        <backtrace crashedThread="0">
            <thread index="0">
                <stackStatement index="0" address="0x61fdd832" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="1" address="0x61f73961" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="2" address="0x61f849f3" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="3" address="0x61f85535" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="4" address="0x61ffb034" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="5" address="0x61ffb051" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="6" address="0x6200136d" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="7" address="0x61ff8606" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="8" address="0x6200135c" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="9" address="0x61e85128" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="10" address="0x61fffc32" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="11" address="0x086a96e0" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="12" address="0x086faa60" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="13" address="0x0018e8c0" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="14" address="0x086ea290" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="15" address="0x620013af" symbolname="DllUnregisterServer"/>
                <stackStatement index="16" address="0x086f59d0" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="17" address="0x2638977b" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="18" address="0x0018e9b0" symbolname="unknown"/>
                <stackStatement index="19" address="0x086f59d1" symbolname="unknown"/>
            </thread>
        </backtrace>
        <registerSet>
            <register name="EAX" value="0x0899b4d8"/>
            <register name="EBX" value="0x087be850"/>
            <register name="ECX" value="0x00005009"/>
            <register name="EDX" value="0x0899b594"/>
            <register name="ESI" value="0xfffff43e"/>
            <register name="EDI" value="0x0836d000"/>
            <register name="ESP" value="0x0018e9a0"/>
            <register name="EBP" value="0x0018e9b0"/>
            <register name="EIP" value="0x086f59d1"/>
            <register name="EFL" value="0x00210206"/>
        </registerSet>
        <binaryImageSet>ETC ETC ETC very long sequences</binaryImageSet>
    </crash>
    <reproSteps></reproSteps>
</crashreport>
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit